# ArrayContains undefined coldfusion

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I am getting the error **Variable ARRAYCONTAINS is undefined.** I'm not sure what the problem is with my syntax.

Here's my code:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfinvoke method="estimatedShipping" state="CA" returnvariable="days"/>
    CA: #days#
    <br>
</cfoutput>

<cffunction name="estimatedShipping" output="false" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="state" type="string" required="yes"/>

    <cfset oneDayStates = ["CA"] >
    <cfset twoDayStates = ["WA","OR","NV","ID","AZ", "UT"] >
    <cfset threeDayStates = ["MT","WY","CO","NM"] >
    <cfset fourDayStates = ["ND","SD","NE","KS","OK","TX","MN","IA","MO","AR","LA", "WI","MI","IL","IN","KY","TN","MS","AK","AL","GA","OH","WV"] >
    <cfset fiveDayStates = ["ME","VT","NY","NH","MA","RI","CT","NJ","PA","MD","DE","VA","NC","SC","FL", "HI"] >

    <cfif #arrayContains( oneDayStates, state)# eq 'YES'>
        <cfset count = "1">
    <cfelseif #arrayContains( twoDayStates, state)# eq 'YES'>
        <cfset count = "2">
    <cfelseif #arrayContains( threeDayStates, state)# eq 'YES'>
        <cfset count = "3">
    <cfelseif #arrayContains( fourDayStates, state)# eq 'YES'>
        <cfset count = "4">
    <cfelseif #arrayContains( fiveDayStates, state)# eq 'YES'>
        <cfset count = "5">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset count = "5+">
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn count />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using? `arrayContains` was introduced in ColdFusion 9. Besides that, there's no need to wrap a function call with `#` in conditional statements.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a self-contained example, run it on http://trycf.com. [It works with CF10 and Lucee](http://trycf.com/gist/0f56fbca61b698ddeab0d823e12419be/acf?theme=monokai). So there is nothing technically wrong with it. You are probably using an older version that does not support [that function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS2EF4F7C2-F41D-42fe-940D-B7C0212FF3D9.html). Check your CF version:

```
<cfdump var="#server.coldfusion.productversion#">
```

For an alternative to this function, take a look at http://cflib.org. They may have something you can use as a replacement, or at least the basis for one, such as [ArrayContains UDF](http://cflib.org/udf/ArrayContains). That said, normally you would store this type of information in a database. Assuming that is not an option, you might find it easier to use a structure. Use the number of shipping days as the "key", and a list of states as the "value".

```
<cfset shipping    = {} >
<cfset shipping[1] = "CA" >
<cfset shipping[2] = "WA,OR,NV,ID,AZ,UT"  >
<cfset shipping[3] = "MT,WY,CO,NM" >
<cfset shipping[4] = "ND,SD,NE,KS,OK,TX,MN,IA,MO,AR,LA,WI,MI,IL,IN,KY,TN,MS,AK,AL,GA,OH,WV" >
<cfset shipping[5] = "ME,VT,NY,NH,MA,RI,CT,NJ,PA,MD,DE,VA,NC,SC,FL,HI" >

<cfset result = "5+">
<cfloop collection="#shipping#" item="days">
    <cfif listFindNoCase( shipping[ days ], stateCodeToFind)>
        <cfset result = days >
        <cfbreak>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

---

Nothing to do with the question, but

1. Always `var` or `local` scope *all* function local variables
2. No need for the excess pound signs in the CFIF
3. Since `ArrayContains` returns a boolean value, it is simpler to write:

   ```
   <cfif arrayContains( oneDayStates, state)>
   ```

   Instead of

   ```
   <cfif arrayContains( oneDayStates, state) eq 'YES'>
   ```

Comment: Change `<cfset result = -1>` to `<cfset result = "5+">` and the example would be correct. ;)

Comment: @Alex - Yep, you are right. Totally overlooked the cfelse ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for ColdFusion 8 and below:

```
<cffunction name="estimatedShipping" output="false" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="state" type="string" required="yes">

    <cfset var LOCAL = structNew()>

    <cfset LOCAL.oneDayStates   = ["CA"]>
    <cfset LOCAL.twoDayStates   = ["WA", "OR", "NV", "ID", "AZ", "UT"]>
    <cfset LOCAL.threeDayStates = ["MT", "WY", "CO", "NM"]>
    <cfset LOCAL.fourDayStates  = ["ND", "SD", "NE", "KS", "OK", "TX", "MN", "IA", "MO", "AR", "LA", "WI", "MI", "IL", "IN", "KY", "TN", "MS", "AK", "AL", "GA", "OH", "WV"]>
    <cfset LOCAL.fiveDayStates  = ["ME", "VT", "NY", "NH", "MA", "RI", "CT", "NJ", "PA", "MD", "DE", "VA", "NC", "SC", "FL", "HI"]>

    <cfset ARGUMENTS.state = uCase(ARGUMENTS.state)>

    <cfif LOCAL.oneDayStates.indexOf(ARGUMENTS.state) gte 0>
        <cfset LOCAL.count = "1">
    <cfelseif LOCAL.twoDayStates.indexOf(ARGUMENTS.state) gte 0>
        <cfset LOCAL.count = "2">
    <cfelseif LOCAL.threeDayStates.indexOf(ARGUMENTS.state) gte 0>
        <cfset LOCAL.count = "3">
    <cfelseif LOCAL.fourDayStates.indexOf(ARGUMENTS.state) gte 0>
        <cfset LOCAL.count = "4">
    <cfelseif LOCAL.fiveDayStates.indexOf(ARGUMENTS.state) gte 0>
        <cfset LOCAL.count = "5">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset LOCAL.count = "5+">
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn LOCAL.count>
</cffunction>
```

I also fixed the inconsistency and properly scoped your local variables.

Comment: Alex - Nothing against the answer, but I would not recommend using indexOf in this specific case. Here is why: [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) is a *lot* less tolerant than most expect after using CF functions. Unlike CF, java's indexOf is sensitive to both case *and* variable type.  A search for `"15"` yields different results than a search for `val(15)`.  Given the potential for unexpected behavior, better to stick with pure CF IMO. At least something more likely to produce the results you would expect.  Just my 2¢

Comment: True, but I think it's safe in this case. He passes in a string and has strings in his arrays. But you're right about being aware of `indexOf`, `contains` etc.

Comment: (Edit) Well since other options exist, I still disagree but .. if you are going to use it, at least upper case `arguments.state`, or it will not find a match if the supplied value is in a different case ;-)